# Как связать 3 таблицы в SQL запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, как связать 3 таблицы в SQL запросе ?
Имею вот такой запрос(связывает 2 таблицы)

```
SELECT categories.title, goods.name, goods.id
 FROM categories
 INNER JOIN goods
 ON categories.id = goods.category
 ORDER BY categories.id;
```

нужно связать  таблицу orders (orders.items_id связать с goods.id)

структура таблицы :

```
 categories|   goods      |  orders
 --------- |--------------|-------------
 id(Pk)    |  id(Pk)      |  id(Pk)
 title     |  name        |  items_id
 ----      |  category    |  ---
```

Comment: покажите структуру самих таблиц в субд

Comment: @Ep1demic исправил

Answer (score 4):

Если не ошибаюсь

```
SELECT categories.title, goods.name, goods.id
FROM (categories
INNER JOIN goods
ON categories.id = goods.category)
INNER JOIN orders
ON orders.items_id = goods.id
ORDER BY categories.id;
```

Comment: Скобки во FROM желательно убрать...

Answer (score 0):

Так я соединяла *свои* четыре связанные таблицы таблицы:
[Мои связанные таблицы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOMCw.jpg)

[image: Так я соединяла свои четыре связанные таблицы таблицы]
Сначала основную связать с промежуточной с использованием LEFT JOIN, затем с этим же оператором присоединить остальные таблицы, связанные с промежуточной. *Всё просто! :)*)
[Понятные правила соединения таблиц в виде диаграмм тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN4Qf.jpg)

Comment: Если использовать INNER JOIN, то происходит объединение данных, и есть большая вероятность, что данные в основной таблице не будут выведены **все**

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Код не добавляла, так как копирование не развивает мышление. Считаю, важно понять идею. А на картинках все наглядно. На девайсах картинки можно увеличить, если что. Незрячие пусть слушают текст, если им надо, в чём глубоко сомневаюсь...